# tkinter won't update entry box with function

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

Lately I've bean learning how to use the tkinter module in Python 3 to create a GUI. Unfortunately I've become stuck on an issue where my Entry widgets won't update. To understand the problem I wrote a short test case that populates an Entry widget with the string 'hello'.

```
class SettingsWindow():

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()

        main_frame = ttk.Frame(self.root, padding=(15, 15, 15, 15))
        main_frame.grid()

        start_time = tk.StringVar()
        start_time_ent = ttk.Entry(main_frame, textvariable=start_time, width=5)
        start_time.set('hello')
        start_time_ent.grid()

        main_frame.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    app = SettingsWindow()
```

The issue arises when I attempt to organize my work in terms of methods:

```
class SettingsWindow():

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()

        main_frame = ttk.Frame(self.root, padding=(15, 15, 15, 15))
        main_frame.grid()

        self.general_settings(main_frame, parent_column=1, parent_row=2)

        main_frame.mainloop()

    def general_settings(self, parent_frame, parent_column=0, parent_row=0):
        start_time = tk.StringVar()
        start_time_ent = ttk.Entry(parent_frame, textvariable=start_time, width=5)
        start_time.set('hello')
        start_time_ent.grid()

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    app = SettingsWindow()
```

When I run the second version of the code, the window loads with an empty Entry widget. My only guess on why this happens is  `start_time.set('hello')` is stuck in some queue and I'm missing a command when compiling the window. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ttk widgets are particularly sensitive to the garbage collector. Make `start_time` an instance variable rather than a local variable.

Comment: That fixed it thanks. Do you happen to know why the tsk widgets are so sensitive?

Comment: @user144153: I don't know. Maybe the guy that implemented it was lazy, or didn't know how to properly implement it. Or perhaps the real question is why normal tkinter widgets _aren't_ sensitive to the garbage collector.